# JSON helper function returning object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am currently trying to implement AJAX search and there I got stuck with JSON helper function I don't know now what should I do to rid of this thing.

Here are my efforts:

View

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#q").bind("keyup",function(){
       //alert(this.value)
        var search=this.value;
        var str;
        $.ajax({
            url:"/search",
            type:"get",
            data:{q:search},
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(result){
              alert(result);
              var obj= JSON.parse(result);
              alert(obj);
              $("#searchdiv").html("<a href='#' onclick='myfunc();return false;'>"+obj[0].name+"</a>");    
            }
         });

         $("#q").on("focusout",function(){
           $("#searchdiv").slideUp();
         });

         $("#q").on("focus",function(){
           $("#searchdiv").slideDown();
         });

   });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query= $request->input('q');
    $search = DB::select('select book_master.book_name,author_profile.author_name from book_master,author_profile where book_master.book_name=? or author_name=?',[$query,$query]);
    return response()->json(array('searchdata'=>$search),200);
}
```

Routes

```
Route::any('/search','AJAXSearchController@index');
```

[image]

Comment: your ajax seems to be working fine, what is the problem?

Comment: First you don't need to parse json if use dataType in request. Then can you please provide a dump of your request result?

Comment: You are already aware of the browser console so there's no need to use `alert()` to inspect variables—as you can see, it casts everything to strings thus it's basically useless. Try `console.log()` and [friends](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 success:function(result) {
   var obj= result;
   $("#searchdiv").html("<a href='#' onclick='myfunc();return false;'>"+obj.searchdata[0].book_name+"</a>");
 }
```

or use a loop

```
success:function(result) {
    $.each(result.searchdata,function(i,v){
        $("#searchdiv").append("<a href='#' onclick='myfunc();return false;'>"+v.book_name+"</a>");
    });
 }
```

change `select` to `raw`

```
$search = DB::raw('select book_master.book_name,author_profile.author_name from book_master,author_profile where book_master.book_name=? or author_name=?')->setBindings([$query,$query])->get();
```

Comment: got rid of this but didn't got any output

Comment: do a console.log(result) and paste what you have in the console here

Comment: blank returning nothing.. in console

Comment: did you test your query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128031/discussion-between-bhavik-bamania-and-madalin-ivascu).